# Redis - Unable to Authenticate

Tags: docker, authentication, redis

I have been trying to set up an Authelia instance for the last week or so and keep running into an issue where it won't authenticate to the Redis instance (both in Docker). I suspected it was because the username I wanted to use needed to be set up in Redis, so I did this and set up an admin account, as well as keeping the existing default account active without a password, just for testing purposes.  Now it appears that I can't access using any of those accounts, including the default, even using redis-cli
.
Does anyone have thoughts on what I can do now that doesn't involve starting from scratch?  Or even starting from scratch would be fine, but this is my third attempt, so would appreciate any feedback on what I might be doing wrong.

Thank you.